# Does OS X Keep A Log Of Downloaded Files On My Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, logs

Does OS X make a record or log of every file that has ever been downloaded on my Mac.

Is there any reason to view them (or even delete them) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEvents.

OS X uses the data in this file for the warning messages that come up when you open a downloaded app.

Comment: I've used it to track an old application I downloaded, but very, very seldom. If you are super-paranoid about such things, you could delete it, I suppose.

Comment: I know the OS uses the data in there for the warning messages that come up when you open a downloaded app.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you add it to your answer (as i added the comment to my question) that would be great

Comment: Thanks for this - it's Oct. 2015 and I have a need to inspect this file on a few remote machines. I'm finding "com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2" (running 10.11) and this file's apparently a binary. Know a good tool I can use to inspect it? Shouldn't it just be a .plist file?

Comment: Never mind, It's a SQLite3.x database, figured it out.